# "No rule to make target" althoug the rule exists

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have an issue with my makefile which says `No rule to make target /obj/%.o, needed by /bin/exec.  Stop.` But from what I understand I have it:

```
# define the C compiler to use
CC = gcc

# define any compile-time flags
# add -DDEBUG for debug mode
CFLAGS = -Wall 

# define any directories containing header files
INCLUDES = -I/includes

# define src folder
SRC_FOLDER = /src

# define src files
SRC = $(wildcard $(SRC_FOLDER)/%.cpp)

# define object folder
OBJ_FOLDER = /obj

# define obj files
OBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SRC))

# define binary path
BIN_FOLFER = /bin

# define the executable file 
MAIN = $(BIN_FOLFER)/exec

# compile object files
$(OBJ_FOLDER)/%.o: $(SRC_FOLDER)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

# build
$(MAIN): $(OBJ_FOLDER)/%.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

# cleaning 
.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ_FOLDER)/%.o
```

I am sorry for any possible major errors in the makefile, this is my first makefile. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @leeduhem yes it does. All the directories exist.

Comment: I am not sure that the target of a rule could be a absolute path.

Comment: You need to add target `all: $(MAIN)`, then just run `make`

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie What happened if you remove this `$(OBJ_FOLDER)/%.o: $(SRC_FOLDER)/%.cpp` rule?

Comment: @qrdl Didn't help, same error. leeduhem, I get the same error.

Comment: Do you really have `/src` folder, not `CURRENT_DIR/src`?

Comment: @alexeyten yes, I have `/src` folder, meaning that the makefile is on the same level with the folders that contains sources\objects.

Comment: `/src` means on the root of the filesystem. Where `/etc`, `/sys`, `/usr` and all that stuff. I don't believe you build your software in root.

Comment: @alexeyten yep, I don't have that. It was clarified already to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(MAIN): $(OBJ_FOLDER)/%.o
```

requests `%.o` exactly. The `%` does not act as pattern here, because it does not appear on both sides of the rule. You need to use the `$(OBJ)` variable there. But it first need to be fixed, because you are only replacing the extension, but you need to replace the directory too.

1. Finish the `$(OBJ)` variable (as Lutin already said) (ok, but I modified it a bit; I presume you only want the direct descendants of the directory):

   ```
   SRC = $(wildcard $(SRC_FOLDER)/*.cpp)
   OBJ = $(patsubst $(SRC_FOLDER)/%.cpp, $(OBJ_FOLDER)/%.o, $(SRC))
   ```
2. Fix the rule to actually *use* the `$(OBJ)` variable:

   ```
   $(MAIN): $(OBJ)
   ```
3. Oh, and you most probably *don't* want `SRC_FOLDER`, `OBJ_FOLDER` and `BIN_FOLDER` to start with `/` as that puts them in the filesystem root it's not where your project lives. And with the patterns above they should not *end* with slash either.

Answer (score 0):

It works with that:

```
SRC = $(wildcard $(SRC_FOLDER)*/*.cpp $(SRC_FOLDER)*.cpp)
OBJ = $(patsubst $(SRC_FOLDER)%.cpp, $(OBJ_FOLDER)%.o, $(SRC))
```